# Como saber se o input do file tem algo?

Tags: jquery

Bom Dia Pessoal TUDO BOM?
Eu estou muito mal...

Gente como eu posso saber que o cara selecionou algum arquivo do pc?

Tipo queria saber essa resposta em true ou false com jquery.

Por exemplo aparece lá:
[NENHUM ARQUIVO SELECIONADO]
Aí quando o cara selecionar algo como eu saber q ele selecionou?

Comment: Coloque parte do código que ja foi feito para ajudar na implementaçao.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer uma verificação se o campo possui valor. Você pode pegar pelo `id` do campo:

```js
function checa(){
   var input_file = $("#file").val();
   
   if(input_file){ // retorna true se teve algum arquivo selecionado
      alert("arquivo selecionado");
   }else{
      alert("nenhum arquivo selecionado");
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="checa()" />
```

> Essa verificação é básica, funciona com `input` tipo `text` também.
>   Apenas verifica se existe valor no campo.

Comment: topppppppppppppppp

Comment: O man mas mudando de assunto vc sabe como eu posso cosnseguir um emprego com isso/

Comment: @OptimusDesesperado Cara, tem que procurar em classificados.

Comment: ok vou procurar , mas venha cá, programador web é aceito somente se souber framework?

Comment: Só sei fazer tudo na mão , e aprender uma framework pra mim agora é tomar uma surra pq minha mae ja ta mandando eu trabalhar e aparecer o dinheiro...

Comment: @OptimusDesesperado Isso é muito amplo. Às vezes uma empresa quer alguém que saiba Bootstrap, outras não... umas quer jQuery, outras não... é bom aprender de tudo um pouco e se virar com coisas que não domina muito. MAs o básico mesmo é saber JavaScript, jQuery, CSS e HTML...

Comment: @OptimusDesesperado E saber uma linguagem backend, como PHP (mais requerido no mercado hoje em dia)

Comment: Sim, meus conhecimentos atuais são: PHP,jquery, javascript(sei ler), php orientados a objetos(SEM MVC pq aprender mvc vai demorar),html css, responsividade com css.

Comment: uso muito jquery

Comment: @OptimusDesesperado Vai aprimorando e procura pegar trabalhos freela que pode dar uma $. Aqui mesmo no SO é um ótimo lugar pra aprender. Tenta responder as perguntas que vc sabe.